# Oracle to Postgres Conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone please let me know how to convert the below Oracle code from Oracle to Postgres Database,

```
select RTRIM(
          XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT(E,
                        (SEC_PROMOTION_ID ||'+'|| SEC_OFFER_ID),
                        '|'
                       ).EXTRACT('//text()')
             ORDER BY (SEC_PROMOTION_ID ||'+'|| SEC_OFFER_ID)
          ).GETCLOBVAL(),
          '|'
       ) SEC_PROMO_OFFERS
from SSP2_PCAT.IE_FOR_SSP_STAGING;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The SO community will be happy to guide you but not do something for you. Look at these tips for asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In addition to Nathan's question, what does that table look like, and what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: To understand what this query does requires some **sample of the XML data**. It extracts 2 values from that data which is apparently stored as a clob. The 2 extracted values are concatenated, not entirely sure why xmlagg() is used, then rtrim() is used. So, to help you further, in addition to some sample data,  please provide a **sample result**

Comment: This is not a code conversion service. When you've made an effort to do that conversion yourself and run into difficulties. please come back and explain the problem you've encountered, including the relevant portions of the code, and ask a specific question, and we can try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a workaround to overcome Oracle's obnoxious limit of 4000 byte for the result of `listagg()`.

This is a lot easier in Postgres

```
select string_agg(sec_promotion_id||'+'||sec_offer_id, '|' order by sec_promotion_id, sec_offer_id) as sec_promo_offers
from IE_FOR_SSP_STAGING
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
This is PERFECT and so very helpful going forward !

Comment: You are very helpful, Sirr!